# How to prevent VS Code to close opened files when opening another one

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't use folders in VS Code. If I have an open (already saved) file, like:

[image: open-file]

Then I close VS Code, and either double click on a different file, or right-click onto a file and pick `Open with Code`, the previously opened file closes:

[image: different-file-open]

[image: file-1-is-gone]

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `window.restoreWindows` to `preserve` ([since 1.52 November 2020](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52#_restore-previous-session-windows)).

Comment: So easy but I hadn't found anything on the internet

Comment: where do we do it?

Comment: @Mandroid You could try Google "visual studio code settings", eg. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: I actually did that, but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not so intuitive, but open *Settings-> "Workbench > Editor: Enable Preview"* and disable this option.

Further visible explanation:
"Controls whether opened editors show as preview editors. Preview editors do not stay open, are reused until explicitly set to be kept open (via double-click or editing), and show file names in italics."